# Behavior of Arrays in a Loop

Tags: c++

Im new to this forum and I want to ask why it is that the behavior of this array Im making is different from I expected it to be?.

```
int main() {
    int array[8]={3,5,5,6,6,5,3,5};
    for(int i=-1;i<=8;i+=2) {
        std::cout<<array[i+1];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> The output of this is: 35637

I didn't know why the result is like this especially the last part in the index 8 which is the value is 7...

Comment: When you access outside of an array you get *undefined behaviour*. That means what it says, anything could happen, including getting a value of 7. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Your program exhibits *undefined behavior*. It is, therefore, senseless to try and find sense where, by lack-of-definition, there is none.

Comment: Incidentally, not that this is relevant or anything, but 7 is the value of your `i` variable at this point. So that's probably why you see 7, in memory the `i` variable is stored immediately after the array. Obviously you should not rely on this, your program's behaviour is just undefined.

Comment: @john I expect it to display the typical display if it goes out of bounds.. I didn't expect it to display 7 rather than the memory address or value.. not 7.. and if I change the value of my to 8, it will display the  memory address or value.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean by the 'typical display'. But in any case undefined behaviour is what it is. You might learn what typically happens when you have undefined behaviour for the type of programs you write on the types of computers you use. But you experience probably won't be the same as anyone elses. The only correct answer to your question is that it's undefined behaviour and it's wrong to expect anything in particular to happen.

Comment: For any debug build you should use address sanitizer (aka ASAN) which is part of clang and was ported to gcc. You will then get a runtime error which will show you on what like you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your array has 8 entries, with the following positions:

```
array[8] = {3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 3, 5}
            ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
 (position) 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

Your loop starts at `i = -1`, goes until `i <= 8`, and increases `i` by 2 each time, so `i` takes the values -1, 1, 3, 5, and 7. Since you're accessing the elements `array[i+1]`, you're asking for the elements at positions 0, 2, 4, 6, and 8. But there's no position 8, so this is an error and the program's behavior becomes *undefined* by including it, meaning literally anything could happen, even at a different place from the illegal call itself (this is obviously very bad and must always be avoided).

In your case, it appears that your program is reading whatever is in the memory right after the end of the array. You got a 7 there by chance -- there could be anything there, and in fact your program may not even be allowed to access that memory in which case it will crash with a segmentation fault.

Comment: I like the schema

Comment: "so this is actually reading whatever is in the memory right after the end of the array" that is careless. The behaviour is undefined; that's it. An implementation might clamp an out-of-bounds access to the last element for example; particularly given that there's no decay to a pointer here.

Comment: @Bathsheba I agree that anything *could* happen, but I think it's pretty clear that what *is happening here* is that some extra junk memory is being read off the end of the array. I thought it would be more helpful to the asker to describe why they observe the behavior they do, rather than the behavior of this program run on an abstract machine.

Still, you are certainly correct, and I'll edit to make the UB clearer.

Comment: While we're at it, I'd like to point out that _"and the program's behavior becomes undefined afterward"_ is incorrect. The entire program's behavior is undefined (there is technically no "afterwards") - the compiler is free to assume this does not happen so it might make [extremely unexpected optimizations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633). Yes, this does not happen here, but it is something to be wary of.

Comment: @MaxLanghof That's a great point, thanks. In my head I was conflating "after you write this" with "after the program executes this", but those are not the same thing! I've edited the answer again.

Comment: @BaryonsforBreakfast It's probably not chance that the value of seven is output. That just happens to be the value of the `i` variable at that point.

Comment: @john Sure, there's a reason it happened, so it's not chance in the sense of "you looked at some random bytes and they happened to be 7 when read as an `int`", but it's chance in the sense that the compiler (probably) decided to put `i` there when that memory could have been anything or nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Your index `i + 1` will have the values `0, 2, 4, 6, 8`, but as indexing starts with `0`, the last index of an array of size `8` is `7`. Hence, you access the array out of its bounds, which leads to undefined behavior. You can fix this by changing the loop:

```
for(int i = -1; i < 7 ;i += 2) {
    // as before...
}
```

Compiling with `-fsanitize=address` or running the executable with `valgrind` is of great help when debugging such errors.

Answer (score 0):

The index 8 (in your case containing 7) is out of the array bounds (0 through 7), so the program shows you what resides there in the memory (it's a case of `undefined behavior`, possibly leading to runtime errors).

Comment: "so the program shows you what resides there in the memory" Is probably why there's no upvotes, it's impossible to tell if that's the case, as you later pointed out, the behaviour is undefined.